# Firebase functions: send multiple notifications based on array elements

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

Its possible for me to send a notification to the reciever: `idTo` which is a string in the database. However, is it possible to use the array-field instead?: `participants` and send a notification to everyone in the array?

[image]

I store my users with their respective tokens at this path in firebase: `Users->{userId}`:
[image]

I've tried changing:

```
const idTo = doc.idTo
admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', idTo).get().then(querySnapshot => {
```

to:

```
const participants = doc.participants
admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', 'arrayContains', participants).get().then(querySnapshot => {
```

Full code:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('messages/{roomId1}/room/{message}/message/{messageId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log('----------------start function--------------------')

    const doc = snap.data()
    console.log(doc)

    const idFrom = doc.idFrom
    const idTo = doc.idTo
    const contentMessage = doc.message

    // Get push token user to (receive)
    admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', idTo).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(userTo => {
          console.log(`Found user to: ${userTo.data().uid}`)
          if (userTo.data().pushToken) {
            // Get info user from (sent)
            admin.firestore().collection('users').where('uid', '==', idFrom).get().then(querySnapshot2 => {

                querySnapshot2.forEach(userFrom => {
                  console.log(`Found user from: ${userFrom.data().uid}`)

                    const payload = {
                      notification: {
                        title: `${userFrom.data().name}`,
                        body: contentMessage,
                        badge: '1',
                        sound: 'default',
                        clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                        // badge: '1'
                      },
                      data: {
                        title: '',
                        content: '',
                        image: '',
                        uploader: '',
                        type: 'chat',
                      },
                    }
                  // Let push to the target device

                  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userTo.data().pushToken, payload).then(response => {
                  return console.log('Successfully sent message:', response)


                    }).catch(error => {
                      console.log('Error sending message:', error)
                    })

                })
                return console.log('failed')
              }).catch(error => {
                 console.log('Error sending message:', error)
              })
          } else {
            console.log('Can not find pushToken target user')
          }
        })
        return console.log('error: invalid path')
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error)
      })
      
    return null
  })
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to loop over the array for each of the users and somehow execute the push notification. Any ideas are welcome

Comment: I don't understand your query using the field `uid`, as the document you show here doesn't appear to have a field for uid.  I suggest editing the question to more clearly explain your goal at a higher level.

Comment: Im using the uid to find the specific user in my database, to find the users device token.. ive updated my question

Comment: I'm still confused.  You added another document screenshot, but I don't understand the relationship between that and the one you first added.  I'll recommend that you read over this to understand how to ask a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The first one is a chat-message containing the participants, the other one is a specific user-document containing the device token. I need to push a notification to everyone (the participants) of the message-document, by finding their respective tokens from their user-documents

Comment: Sounds like you just need to query for that document, iterate the participants array, and send messages to them.  Where are you stuck with that?  There's not enough information here to know that.

Comment: yes exactly. But i dont know how to iterate over the array of participants. Ive tried: ".where('uid', 'arrayContains', participants).get()" as stated in my question but this does not work.

Comment: The document you're querying with `uid` isn't the same document that has the participants.  You will need to get the document with the participants if you want to iterate that list. As I mentioned before, its not clear what the relationship is between these two documents, but if you don't have the doc with participants, then you won't be able to do this at all.

Comment: no its two different documents, one is a message document the other a user-document (this has the specific users token).. from the message document, which has a list of all the participants, i want to, for each of them in the list, find their respective tokens from the user-document, and then push a notification.

Comment: The current setup works with the string `idTo` which only notifies a single user, but i want it to use the array-field `participants` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
           var messageToSend=req.body.messageToSend;
  var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
      registration_ids:regTokens , // Id List if more then one recipent
      //to : regTokens, //use if One recipient 
      data: {    //This is only optional, you can send any data
          score: '',
          time: ''
      },
  notification:{
      body : messageToSend
  }
  };
console.log(message);
    fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something has gone wrong!",err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
            }
       });
```